# Migrate kafka from server to docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

How to migrate from server kafka (as service) to docker?

I tried to copy all data from kafka and zookeeper data directory to new place. And started docker container. But have a problem. Zookeeper can not see kafka brokers but can see topics.
example:

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh host:port
ls /brokers/ids
[1, 2, 3]
ls /brokers/topics
[__consumer_offsets]
ls /kafka/brokers/topics
[__consumer_offsets,user_topic_1,user_topic_2]
```

Comment: What do you mean? It "sees" brokers 1,2,3.

Comment: Yes it sees brokers, but no user created topics. 

I also tried to use kafka-mirror-maker.sh, but had problems. Not all topic messages was migrated to new kafka cluster.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't update the correct settings. Can you please show docker commands or compose file? You should just be able to mount a volume from your existing broker's `log.dirs` and same for Zookeeper `dataDir`

Comment: And `user_topic_1,user_topic_2` aren't user topics? What else do you mean? Also MirrorMaker 1 is deprecated - you should be using `connect-mirror.sh`

Comment: I will try connect-mirrir.sh 
how you used connect-mirror.sh ?

Comment: do you mean connect-mirror-maker.sh ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. The documentation for that is in the Kafka github under the Connect folder tree

Comment: Maby you know how to migrate internal topic "__consumer_offsets" messages?

Comment: MirrorMaker2 should handle this by itself. Or as stated, mounting the same log.dirs

Comment: MM2 worked fine, but it didn't replicate topic __consumer_offset data from source to target.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to. It creates a separate checkpoint topic for active/active scenarios and keeps the destination cluster `__consumer_offset` data unique from the source in order not to override it completely. Once again, you don't need this to containerize an existing broker

Comment: I don't need data from this topic? What data is stored in this topic? This stores information about consumers status?

Comment: You don't need MirrorMaker. Yes, that's what that topic contains

Comment: I am using connect-mirror-maker.sh to migrate data. It done the job, but I nee also data from __consumer_offset. Maby you know something how to do this?

Comment: Like I said, that's not possible using MirrorMaker. Your Docker image is being treated as a unique broker with its own unique offset topic. If you want to literally containerize an existing broker, just mount the `log.dirs` and `server.properties` from the host; that's it

Comment: Yes I want that, but I had problems with this aproch. What do you need to see the problem? configs?

Comment: What kinds of problems? What specific error message? I assume you have read this page? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/operations/external-volumes.html#data-volumes-for-kafka-and-zk

Comment: Yes I read this page.

Comment: Okay. You say you had problems with it. [Edit] your question to include those details